# Checking if a key is unique before inserting, if not make another key

Tags: php, mysql, key, duplicates, unique

Basically I need to insert a random key along with the users ip address and web browser into a MySQL table; This is for authentication etc and this key must be unique.
However, I seem to of found that the use of "goto" in php is hugely discouraged, I need to make a random key, check if it already exists and if it does create and check another key else just insert the key.
I tried to to use on duplicate update but it didn't seem to work at all:

```
INSERT INTO fkey (fkey,ip,browser) VALUES ('$subhash', '$ip', '$browser')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fkey='substr($sessionID,$rand,$rand+29)';
```

I am unsure of how make this process as efficient as possible, I tried having an continuous while loop of which is only skipped if the key if unique but it turns out while(true) is also discouraged.. Admittedly I could use now() etc to assure uniqueness but I am also simply just curious on how I could solve this without the use of such.

So I could solve it through current using time and dates in the hash but I am just curious of how this is done without that.

```
function fkey($sessionID, $mysqli){
    $hashed = hash('sha256',$sessionID);
    $rand = rand(2, 34);
    $subhash = substr($sessionID,$rand,$rand+30);
    //$subhash = 'b4';
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    recheck:
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM fkey WHERE fkey = ? LIMIT 1")){
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $subhash);
        $stmt->execute();   
        if($stmt->num_rows > 0){    
            $rand = rand(2, 34);
            $subhash = substr($sessionID,$rand,$rand+29);
            goto recheck;   
        }else{
            if($ins = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO fkey (fkey,ip,browser) VALUES (?,?,?)")){
                $ins->bind_param('sss', $subhash, $ip, $browser);
                $ins->execute();
                return $subhash;    
            }else{ return "fail1"; }    
        }
    }return "fail2";
}
```

Comment: do a select on your random creation. if it is not there do an insert. a duplicate update would blow way what was already there for a different user. so loop, create a new random, test it

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that but I need an efficient means of doing this. that way would involve loops and more than one query, I am sure there must be a way of putting that into one query through the on duplicate method. *edit* I probably should of mentioned that these keys are only valid for a current users session. Though if this is the most efficient method then I guess I'll just have to go back to the while(true) loop, ugh.

Comment: the problem is that you think that by calling 1 sql routine it is faster than calling 2. if you think a select on an index is slow as compared to the dubious uncertainty of blowing away data on a duplicate update, then by all means continue to outthink the dbengine and do it your way

Comment: Sorry, I don't actually know. That's why I'm asking for advice, if you're right in saying a loop is the most appropriate I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pre-populate a table with random unique keys. in the example below i sucked in 100 from a previous create to determine the speed in doing selects. note that on my dorky mysql box creating a row of varchar(128) or 110 can do about 20 per second. but a select can do about 12000/sec. if you secure your mysql appropriately, can say have an index on id plus the random key plus a column specifying if it has been used yet, and load up say 10k, you can just use them, and mark them as used. there are a 100 ways to do it. if used you can always delete them.

```
<?php
$authids=array(
"0N9nFd8mIkyWYh0Nw7ZW5LGrGLEy93saQBxwOFSx0rtYJuMgCMcHxT9dEOMORfYIQveFb7dbyHaicXyOJLvhFEvkti8kx73oCh4Ooh0XZbgb8P",
"odgKwd1SXazjyevKMRFcNIhJXUOtUn8iBp37C40AfzTNOpxBgcN4V4NTZBmUZvdAVgHxlH8Ah1o6rVIH8wL4AzXAbkvaPILKYsikarUssiyUeh",
"4e9pc9oGFvMMJBRbyQr2xSneVVlzE6xJkH9xQxdw30iMC9Xb0pdxhBLcw7MbekVy246TCkpFkHsXRp8RPlp6Xbjti5FwqB5tGcmiwLYQtrOlRX",
"Y1WtAdCpF0JmDxBRxi4c3XaKRuj6H1bF388ElL30LMmokYgShl4kif4aKohrqs6tAf7W1bXNXjbiisazNeT6uYhemyFM0MgA1ow3ztQxN2P6u0",
"qURs5KjQNiLzW3YYTFYEBOmaiMUomXjMRafWUyMIRyiNChLwWJaxywIQjCfFAysrJHoDgam8JEVmVHSRr2pZz7QSK5ykE1MnIa0Zlm7513rWLj",
"7sNG0Sh9wpX6td6eqkAanNzZ2hgLawShYFYZyf94F6b8jimKCXUZKuYMLexVLqdK5bKErUJ60UekcB4PyZOitM4f1CaN2ny8yjM0dv6dqlyDXD",
"YxOtazf0TtwkGezi5R30DVBVpXkP7xL64zAe9Pe2jLnZ0Xi5Om6shHnHFHwNfiTjRty0jN3DyrDyoWEdiKFAs3h7LOV06PjYjSZDF3geuUNTQr",
"st6JfSN9r1qCc0yRGp8izo12XggkZkWrN3b3VYcn0DZcDx4kXcCwAEzyUQSTaPlYSw1OvebvRaIvIMPGYrdz5M7ZD0TNPeMILOxh2INUTvpCif",
"jOhaI6eJa8C648rqcogyMjhe2LudixUClcM4i1Ns9pzey0EKpVibfAqhmVvFsqhOC3SV5Fnf5XtDY8nn3GzihZADU6inwAb9E34JIsYOpsrnAP",
"atPdkwKXseCFzL0j4qa5dhCEBJ0cjJ7ucWIxtsuWH7BgTCAX2K3g1GVDqWPJFWdSSWplpUh61TmUwWSzHVPIBLl1HaLm7ZeZVElkyDrzxNu3Km",
"8GVpFlt6KOBCFvH2EeTzGXroO0CHxSjGyf5eAyllnWY2sF56TYGAV7YK7AsFtMl21rgC0BXnyWp1Bv7vtN5pV4a2FCI8o4apvr2v30TCWjDxOK",
"s50W5ccqzkkpHpd63Y6bvzgd53qy1EntJoqOADfaXzzFYMM1KSdgrttxxU6zyu2iSt7t6mD4WcJVZwXJoa0QEuocouLXYNfRhnknKYsHbcCaIA",
"kk8icwACb3j2Z2OM3lHJOXMJrSdJg8LAtTSFqsiBwBEwEtiIPZrDXemo6z7nITYbNRRdk9PRKtopWH8MGApEPM2Vmaj53ihQ984uhTl2mJrjqA",
"PKXIenpXnSHcb759PwpfhcsiiaOSo4xdPuW3Sm1geItpQyzG4YVmboEtyslWxSamn7pftrwI9Z70xGGCFCYQ0Cky5FvCyGYVNobhPHZYG7YeOF",
"LxjdBBup57A3O72a9AS2fZ2ck8Wx0moMUIZvjuVpBvtqCwAM6sPlsSyM0uk1QJNLrNgLhcaTHEjkaU7gnWCQOaDPEXQvHEg8rxUJJ5CrJWLURS",
"cM55TkqyiAeQcIBlPiy2JAFSWZkAHz2Tl8YftoNLZ1CbKdwzw4BfFg8BgsbX1eRnnPCQeqCdseocrVLXZndFElhUOtSQHJe5zRVNhx0JMoVejH",
"LBzYGkuWRw69WjnuBtIoledEB5YJiYK4Aj2gDxdv3jE0D1vfvdEQrSu3YtMgrxl2RoiuVwZZPEZtGuJbHn29fxce0ZusxPvoeNS9jS99w8DcDm",
"qPKAWimz39YF3D4ERIwy2sxlTdY7LsqcibMft9OwjNcmrg1iZxR10omTCl1nNsz6Dml7waEQXQdo7eH6Mz7NYuHAPIYDaxJOU5VqfzhdquCxJk",
"bihI6mrkSuYChEoWbDkIJpnOYqDERdk2wBKCXcWQHVsZzRWLvgtfFR3EhGj8UDbrfW3d903QVwPvoLhT2K8HBcmTTF2Nidey9iLijO9ekYKIK1",
"SoarFLmefQrI4UuQGcUsDQDYTHLaxFnp4yRJkeYz4ph9jLZZYUsCK6BDNmOl2cL6KCQ4QODVdV4xG4xFZZhJ5SnTfcehoZo8Cedt3RohMtOtxl",
"ITouzjkXHnRoelxMwR3pdh6hyg0RKOTtHiYgBiejG6IVrfHX7Lnk2tBAKBsvqlZ7EXofgDyWJhSbwz8DkwXmZzXKbpfBLfJpc7FsLepuvhF1RO",
"2mOoHz4XnfFre7qcQvNd4z8rEA5OjQ7lcVJUvORS4xjiEKuvghIkQRLvrQjKHr6TmQNREFKId40RPvn5N5pEXb9o2t9JUfDh6r9K7TtkYucNZz",
"EquImfHavYc7dGT6Mjdo8xXbSZ72CnehOIZaXHltGxATeu01NepWLn8EmfHZDVgrEgCCXX5DvGxJbyKZMaWyx4dUkUTXQaovr17pYd3tUBd69Y",
"WReLfasvrh5B88shBqp22zTImE47Zv3VmiHCs98TreuAnXSYni0qST9exdlxJot6HaI9kR3L5xmsverTxrkpltDTHZqqnTw43feo7h9cPwFlL6",
"huA2kum0baUvNg2se6Ui0MswlIYezvgQZRTklfkwqf2dw4FKaz2amvHIdGWNbdDb4xvpMQWc6YqC26mcFpn2U5K8LHVXUz9Z6FoTwk5CiwelCB",
"cttEp6bR9jTz5Q6yc1vGYISECws0fqusTX6j3ibdC4MHUTg7VMOTuGx7c08srCUlz1FDjQQWUDDPxUXsGLmbrUiEUq6l20HC1mglc7h7LVXiPU",
"GP2q9Ga6DF9X2xKc5VKX0UmTYejmh3UXTXo2Ez9ieifgP0sUVdSW7eP6t8tKcnI5l67ZFhiUzxaoyDjuQbqYqg4TpxEBVnGhuOh95z3E7e3FRm",
"iSSchAs9ZP6GqUAC2pv7q9Dp2Fv9sRrKKkX1UpbUfhBFbcieBOm1XZr0EWa7OBSyVPAQfLLu2maeystahPbeODftApAo1tXXixNyjy2mVdBtG4",
"zODIdKbMCGbVK3tkJAxli94546Cy0UNAJqiWauINbUIVXcfGMN24W690dMzeGnOqN7nYB6LM0uIXGYEsLGxINHJ0tjfaG3BuaYsM5ez5Ih3pgH",
"GU2Qs5dbmTncpSI7mDIJKteP5dfp6n0Ni2DK8RWuKkGacphz30jNuxDzKSYRgZFy2ijaafEUzl5MLnlOoEBScerX7qPnpuWsNfCXvhS5CXSold",
"q766yMq6TV58WK70sArvZKIkFmqqSAGiHNpfzPltLqCHbJIDk98kTREzd505FHonuNC4DYxop95BTOedXnxRecrrisxY9VlDIXImWfKlpQWiFb",
"nVWyU0YqWuygwZjL7vPppXTqP4dDFpu3lqBgrAGn4fEBeYmmtcMT9GkYKxCpX7six3zZDfnIv1kJ0G6uTSn2yH1ieEHbL9ujd3iRiGzNHTxHAE",
"hFSt1bfzMxusEMRng2w3wBUQaSFe2COkiGNkS2TEAo6eaYBr07uwJpnTh38kGWEYCsiuuc94BgjLeUde2ILM78FpcOJSKoQmQ8Rll1pWhJIvDV",
"Tw7lU5cAefnywt9tFWAeki8QJKvhYa6RGdcBjpbyEz7a2gEIdeWyw5pgPUyN5EFMSSnchzKW8R6a8LSmZPVwUkMKfkykZe6R6u4n3OjbGqmPbf",
"2dW5Qq9RkWpXQwZl2LGeOEA7woMkh1cje9p5zzXUwmRmSQIUCo8r2Jzz8lTqn6JCf9HPIFJe1ABUrjP4IYvLH5lQqegOl0qB98qSO96PKIKb2z",
"mycn55dTfLHIz8N7pNwRV585lNH5od9LLm8RrmLH7spHAdO00lSWr01MNJScW2XIo6zQskxANXhna5nbrf7Sf9E3SxfPAdxZk6QMrnnelEBwKZ",
"Vy07268pzr0XdxSds8zfLNNO947SWXERvFYyL7XlzYiMvaZYjzd5m0Uw51o1Z3TvIS3uZ0PyZ8lujlsDUGIhHCNMEcODgH8Yzbszci8bqtFJO8",
"pUYpffU5tksQ5Ai3xChkfdSH87IUE0m3UlsaBng4HIVNjdQRQ8b6l3NubvpPwMSr7lCIJSNqBJeUW5LNdXTz0G4cct1IfUangM6ZETqgDEaAKW",
"GmRyQwiAhUDlJlQQrIF0wjwnlFCBsGF82xHT30tlU6GDsxuTg9UMtq9P6Mqys6HuDpoHpR2jYJXqgrkwBei5EsUKekjGq0b4pzLOrO8px5QOxa",
"jsSWAdSCUd2DtMZez84fG7C5epU21Gvk8ohIC9kwmn9Pa94Ji8ZYfB4u1Yx3E3oMrFv4PPAbdJ1nS57ae69uIdYKbvNPycC0R75GXFSapTxhZF",
"Z0PB4nV3QgFjGUOjzSxSHyKQDxZ9U84T8Tuchqg8HVrnQfGq7eiPN2FqAFAuNEnWyS9QipY0lpnbF4CNjUC6XixxY72MLpIkiRaAh8BDyZOd3r",
"XzGH8PX6AUK9gEF8LgyqBNHcsyGxJkwGTcn21l9CgUMxysFkIeKj2swu1d1LxysrKQuMbDpsxbZ6DFqlTbFVDbqForqW0SoKISwUwVn47maL2B",
"VgtOicMMkzONnCQmJezC02JmsoWSRQYN7sBpEocZX1MlECHoQh0RjKdL9aD01CO95pyJOLJLNv7r8OQZ5QQpB4bKfOLhrzrwZZgNLZyzvF0DuR",
"hmew39W3lvjmrYP4aTEusVJQFDHNr9YIwcezmbCHGW48UTc4NQzgMj6rWOfnXd5tqk2MvFucBykvsxAfo9vasCCpqRMn4SQudTgIyLVajgGMNg",
"qETGm4HI5YdsvRC74ytdjQgObMLchjqIXkojp51v3fYz6AHa8ans1Egcr2pImQqjbPDAVF5YU4y1EgbNqzfsdwEEz4nVVNf6DTGyzMxuQ6vvmG",
"YCptaRL4cGizLZDUD5pDZjYvSAsOIrBH41afSVj5CCEoBiifnHTn1RSUrkIaMkRRl16eXpjz2XXEfgTCXMZZDST5dBfZV7Rh8Xv5nOFpMD31TW",
"KsM5f3iqqnGBmW6bKnfVeeNd3N7vsoKdRxj6ABx1YdDlaJwU7LQl0Ez3rGzT4k6WRp3r1As0O5lYPSTXEJjEnSIOyhIDBPzseCUgdng1sCZivS",
"BqKCKeFgfvoGG7hPuYmJFCHD1E5VaoVMOGpzU5QaAeQgm86Q6tAL5hp7Wu27SYTHFigzo6KYlBfHJlxQO7BUp11lv4so2m6HFmh3t22PDhwnC3",
"Fq16e19wyk0SGBiJT15ZSfufb8Hv9ElO5mVko4QXpQP5s7Pm9Ul1aQhlYYQ8DcWJyS3XWUUlKJrcQhzZbU1mLiHKgySUKPDjHGgEAaZlUryLI7",
"tiqE3JZUXeTnrLTr9lXPztDlhvk8o5ZSnpxr8wl6Keuc0nDaJA0i4DEl9Yty4tqrTYT2uf8fuCru04EJFE2JiG5sFy0J2rbVp4YUk69OJAiKFW",
"l6IzJkUTsUhfGupzFoh9S6YiU7iKOxi9D1JmlEgOyy4f3uOIS6SLcQ36XmQLU9VxaFUwkblSJq8MUXvN3nygdCmaYdWSnSqxxl4RwqKfQS2KQx",
"gFZM1YcX89sRuJnJBFzVoO1rrfIJ1zIhfI4hGgePqHGVq3E1JdW72YyuehdfRWx6FCnlTCajjReKUTMD7JK9IjEWBScsPJzulXQfz0yTSNEMHq",
"T9ndbkiCjsLYc5e2CTswLuEe74PtmyXgIktUFLwZeiYqncsZ5VvRpa6weV0BuYRcjl6Y7DYlVWLi8eieaO5zYb6d67OB5FNo1Un8xltsifLqt4",
"IhfRwL3hZCXyAGgHhZxSGLidh2nn5U8NbnEI9I08lYHVEYDWXaPEV7SdafBgaJ3l6I4gr5pM36II4lE2vtHrBzEMPf2ZY6l5OpmfuL2ySKgX5V",
"ubp25oyvBzdAPuXfdzFPWPBHnKPCV4zpgYsln1RZA4AqyxFL7lB3acKyXzaSEKhUIJg6K75lbGLKerwlM7oXj9vgJF8npqi8ayeVFkhR02Beu7",
"CGYZyYgumosn5RFHyi3eJAYEu7lIMJspqqoYoFtK3V88NOPl6TzQtxvXFQFrA8Q0yfZWUsHYoQ6cEWxLP7BiF6fkXVMx3CxCSxyN0gLp6RBKO9",
"DUkxkYp7hsLTdZoVHFcYkPwqroX4Bdae8vLstbzLElESk3N2J013PxthWrlxFwLN1xfuIPgmaUevY2xH3zKS6ea3FvAk1l72SnxBdNYnIdTGfr",
"eNWdhPqwdZXOaJF6ata2CQ0zgKzhBxoPkk3B9t8nt5bDORKZlU2XL2w1N6ioDGeY1hAaKIxeOJRCABCVwETiHqjuxCTaj89kpJvas3ogMgSnSv",
"bWUlH46vDHt9S3Mq9nypDfaeV2si6W1iTWDB0K6ErANjEAKOYidBxnPsqhLxeMP7JsJJcPoEqcY4MISL06mxub0VtMsHyhPiKy1XopBOBAToiM",
"fBQXJSpThFBGhWqqKE1VvJzavLu6xf6NRWLBPbu6R5M82dyMSzHnjhyO22VAi1o9YaLNlfUclGlnUT9MtQaM8IBbLwL3yadwkZkFeeSzVdXP66",
"qjVf5QkfQ35PqjjiASIO543M0WWR4XXugTKmJ5Bz8Gpy0IQABypHCstDoqvtnsYElJ05OCFWi4ujNkUoTj5vMy9bZEFn7D1tn2ybEe8XiDg5Xa",
"6B4HMtvdSC1wkwSyknp8K7wUSumEmASsbXaYqGbjidPCJIb45AcPIIKAd7eAH73T4dSvU4OchEP1m05sBhij03Tea8OSfSLj6DO0HDcZh10D25",
"K830rbGVtSK7juL9r1z7BuHuEi0SbjDVsGVUSCPmuAtN4fWwhwDT1lnGEoyPIbKaSG4LiT7NtBByRy484I154pMINkxvwiFoZJaiCh55TGDKeI",
"cvu0CGhQ6WtOBQr3QyHVhHQY6wBfRwt32X4FEmvKiYzTP0XGzEBRmsQsYrIQXbU08YFNkaxC96wZ7tFG7hyuKoWJPFzNQtNZrsMLDkoNrUMyns",
"kigZu2NNulOIMVaISMhPCncHrEwkKHr50I4uKShfe6X028IUU0JxnWePBL9msBrtjwX3pfiDlgDnomijn1QLY5AzQKVjlnMETKHj0ZWmfAJEX1",
"Ia8V0TKTQqjfwgDhViO9yS7mklsDCXfk8ng9h127rlnXC0fxj3HSWPegaHUNE98MxoVPpXWRjjPVk4tE8bw50LlbsfY6p6TXvOMVMJM53B1oGu",
"BkbMxpytzfJC2GkJdEQPswRfspfIcLLN6XzDm77VnQxqwR9Kw0AYxrd0RtI3fuQlrqYNx6JVWhlt8vdEwOD4fQ46kNazh0VJrUxZ0gUWxgqGME",
"CEr30TZQjsoDIioxU2HItVrLKKXMqev3TW6UQ6L9y9NgsbOmew5HrwtbhqXIFsLypSsfYeoxncOPnCbB8hjANNL4eJNTcysBrVRq9gXwsMmQpy",
"ZcDrYZgAwPfFuL7NEDaplCh1owXOGRnF41730nDxdSdHElviYFHkiZmGvjucbSSfT0jUoWsBPGjt1PM0utlNtHuZ0ZbcR4sL5LGtI94xPo0RdM",
"FgbbzPxV3TAO9vntafzJPrxkXtYfyk7dBjpa8W5cPG0ZcosmE25ttDOr6MGF7NTI7iSgeYs3Et2RRvdvyiZ2VNt2AaHHYAp5Til7hObWheN9K0",
"G2iksg0BqF666j6ehDYrOmmLeOgbC3Yj6gEyxE9Xkf4qzaERNDiBZEnesEq5HppOF3mcHwa1Leslo7ccKuOK9cYCQpIxO7mubIHTeSV06nlvux",
"lx2uuHAB8Dv3gBv44nVEbvC7HVsCXjMiRONlwnWE1sHi4dm8BiNMNqUvmn8jGUCyJpTfNQTOjB6nOtwqLjczJ655udpb81JRrC7ft14MCbarEG",
"ndTuvo5rf9z8fKN257Xzxv4hx0qtHxS5KMzfbEHqOgz31m66u4G1zKj7LKAthsy2f8iqNZQBgqEhMKngO3hnOBuAl53DyCFNKXdxX48duNuhxS",
"IZjZpi8QGYJuzm2MWIF71kdF8QKRDCOmB7l1puR6tBB2XDPTmu1nPf2X6MPJpE50Mr2cVUipvTssxhmTMohBDjzJ6osv3xwPYz1UtjkYcMrK4O",
"uL2HZzCLbXwuXjzKZNz3I0UfY6ofqrwVcyCc8fXjcuOaNnUNbuQTvL8uRxJiYfebNQoV6lfjP4tDsoqDThwo2ESTbCcaRqlFhKBn5RGVVaynzZ",
"ertQ2OgnJhhU0oTYcBZ2rRqqH6X1gNAve4lhSCFCTXxTlqSx2SzuJ0Ur7SsnF3TT7fbZSRCLO9F9AyHCqh69h0BoT3My7GseWDeOvQAj0gtBOa",
"axhzfC01R9pPcQTmSurHoBtTg1bgwVGHtXgJzhKrq9gD09ZTErA224Vj57AB2gjwdzfMQZdh9uU9DU2ilDkoIfHNmippyJVLiay9aMrkgmtUhw",
"yW2ZjPJufQH20BNFUhh4bKjf3iUGH4vf0xejmYNCOvEP7ru1JM5UwpaAH4go8LE8jTsGRgiGLWvSo0U8M02jpdT7h9vpVaye30UVgdB297Vy8P",
"3EPE0AOATEvLmmMKFgnqlKrYmyEuweWATMfUm4ufIZ14mOO24csqWUpjs3NZhKzbxP5TTz9CzbGVZvX4HpvEjUXMXLLfwkq3avX357FEimziRx",
"lIFXKnaTNVpKogH4loOzwORMW7hdyR6TzMQk91dXXDIlUpqfNfOk4F70NodmfkgP66ag8nd61WsVlTa98YtcEBdsZrOfL45Sbf8kCmqDiSyELI",
"RxQYzRmeXaH2z4DYn4vne3g3Gv3aOy5F5VDFM0TJbBLKFoJ3tfqHiHLZcOa0mfGsak8Xk2GvDsgjRZmkeN2xuNwHBGIYWor6Iz33BKzfdPz5PW",
"m2XDtyGA7OaTlPrd83duMlsMtzjsQ17d45QxDw8LliEG85Ug98LVtdIWN1pE2xR7CIEgfM1B5FidLduUlfQOtyLhzbVCINKlwoBLbCnhiFu3SY",
"vx2GgVws5IjA0dLh95HlANlIeZWWZI4ug6bw2IY7qiIrvtIFyq19emRslOolwtPMA0jCIhJ9zsA5VjKuJLDX7vqtjPOQiEDSEWvnefwOH6TDqD",
"Vow5UBOk67xApFGo5FV76SRkEK1rEVJAjfGdRuxXC5y2KfrPUmX1fOlTznlei5OCluPcZnaCtIEdX63St1TIPfCpDYDW3sypWnBWLLyeudssjv",
"L1bOIuHK47U9ZA0mXftuqDeOMbctx5Jj6U7PpPztXtDW4Dj1TMwjqL7cWkFupoOwjWlILUcIoPFstYumL1FcNMoK74ewt22NYowKjItHy9a18F",
"N4z2567XL5VftWgCF9Blcl0vl87u86lWaUYg06dMb91F6iiLrT7De89Agh4onqlykkOlq28Bcagisz4UscyHlHiBYn0mNlU8FJt5MCHYMYgfxl",
"ufGydCn9U7gPXthq2tWDmOrOPaMsxvV2LBAYeY895oZ3ShtVKqy6e0V4bHwIdrKY3lWhj4rptqsmHWhsmQzAQuE2cbKpCvoFRlXbpoATO3fwZx",
"DqRtFnN99tvNaHfbQ7vsSb5rCHFAyvwbVoFALsKVWgI7YYiP5OhXZnpC45cDAJPv7u6TXRPT7x05wjUC7cA7AZJF5ViFF7bNCiGz9vtg3tmANh",
"rs1tlZoMZMAINnM7tPUCBDxOgbCupqeRTgkefJ1fwBYjYKrrAm4c0B0gMCLc3Z3Wgobv8cLEOJYMuqe5MihMUi2HUNTYNXV3m6zujk8746Uyw8",
"Ts4f9XBjDiVbcvmk5toQ75QIIqxT77l0AqgJnS21aYcmuzHA35qabgTUHrOOzaO9A5TYXVZ7UcupMbZPhp0tGUnolccUm14X6XV3TVbO8FdURd",
"SxFyVnxRiYfOq7DzVFZmO7K8BArT9dl2L0AGn8xG6NvwU86QN6dCdXKOxcIHp3Ja4jRssp8ycD56LbXzhabv7WkF83ny76JbqADS0MrcpwjbIg",
"tWt4iG0oLa0sDVKFR6CTWRgnUoJE7MNAIgF1XFqIQrbunV9e1L8XDolxM4cURZvAgaBdP2WGt7aQ3k545d2JBngostjjsOUIYwWOySu20FT3ZY",
"KcoCIpyGHuAZgIUbiSwETvvbhdNsEXGo951SuAyc49ckR6w9Y3OSzj4QxRibOZAY5CQAcoMhxZCp58z4cnWLH0CfSUrGU1F0DvAQUn7smJSsSr",
"hy4fkKzFgkZ3mnKWALnBz7DgE4U0mQsEpxTJhtpyOpBaNl7n6uZGCCXhGRi2HKH7hARy4h6SGI3t3aQaFQQhsNy9EQcmBTuSulryDyqjguMjED",
"e3UF9UrIZeq0lQwJyfZW4X41bjLGuHwJLroUlPDl43lqTR9r69ob6tchMXYgFvZqWnkhdYCh1YHUPRmW0L77ejp1hohWTgnPEI7RGK9IIQCxIZ",
"3G8GRWiEJrZ8sWZN1KefnJPamjwIxmnB3wiUtAyd2yluuliw5xMsgBDCUaksxH4AemvHX4UZCfu7ANEGkq9A2NdWXypugu5uQBbNF5NiliqW54",
"BROaRc01Bi5Nm8YROG48qzv6qVyMMlTodIy4Uz6vSbjejh58XagoJMu9I3WvpPTCysGt1MYTYi8hAdpxnGW6sqgbucGT2zwA2c33Z2XXl5fVjE",
"1ZKUZExDSkm8vhMPyauwvaCKiKflxVDyVnsU20yUkV3QdQFL09hwkUgCFvXcrALnYdi1dQWyMZoZP4KQd2mxXDaC97PBIAYGNgI17EATDZSt3D",
"lRQ5ICYaUts23qtvnciSvO07afGRql1LcSRUvP5pjxrmXVSl7bdCZeJ9uq1UL2GYUxSqnXPHvg4tbWPj83V7hFhM5iGRknPfVIFiGvZbM4FY0u",
"MfYv6zz44riLbZypKMIuMP2pCvC3b06Yg5tnE2rJuKvFJ34uQNYDC13fwFiIGpGWuaj9cLSHvnmfrrJieIWRJZ7gFqYlPEhkOAt1mmIRK56cwP",
"vb7HdgT2gzCSqpYBlUgUqCAMFaTapd3VoaCCqwFH5hAwHy73snXT0yFGIzQ7MT3b3FNucsbiKLOskVvMjsGk0m0JVRRIKUUOAHjMav5VgTnBPT",
"VHcDudoFJlOK2zQkG9TrD4MTvGBDKu3GbfjGtHmc3bW5LNqrWjTAoFuUm5x6zBMLR6skOPxR0uXMhndeG6P5MjZ8pwfY72KY8djX2QO3lMPC93",
"IDVsOUowXyOgdQdqleazNyXKxrA1EXmnAhPpceWaMKq0AErWSBvF9tpGV0HzY4XzlMYx0UHNE8OfMfcFQIk0cKH7LpHJtEjPrhnsc4fRd470jj",
"PuxrC4isrB0yKCKdAKzGB1mekuy2A43pyBRbG9D7LEGvgqJRbixNkU1EozHZEKpcmgn2q19bFPHWgqNsJlf3ggIEQpEva3Hxk5zK6JWMyDIP3w",
"1KMBUUsLZ5glS9iaCmRo1Jdgynh2dUQfECQzxjkwpBShKarnwjLy2YPBm7DA1tPG6GgDZAapc2GWc8kJr6hu475reJ1fcRWjxcXxN7WZaDWnLg",
"ui1RgxCE4NYhX60iHIxcH4Xu1UzO5KrA3srk03Y4QXmO3m7L5EXMIVhKPQzUA0vEtWYuZXyQUVFXhMJmqH99CqUrgtmRtRvXOurNr0ElVjjc53",
"nXgaGfGrSd5Pzi4wIU0RyEpqqhHxZjdmhuwXKcoCpurZMwvvrvn09NrA4973slpJQWHA86dyAFxnc3TDzgEJ35j7eqaHLArCx8cFfqeP5MdiP6",
"xTwWVuZg8VQ6g8oVaZQ3k1LWKKDwww24qy1l31BcXsidAH8KHZO11zXLkBhR7kVxSXTWZv9WXs9x9iiQi6SjFP40qmRyGN5zKZwKuFGr7PZh8h",
"RPS2v1aKYXTKasS4p9vKfSpkMczJRlxJapMFqWppTj94L28acEUrxkMjxm3pHB8S0UxrRXQKg0P13YcfD7GartuZPyox9xparWBiUs3atTcwSo",
"Z3qxUzfB6ociXot7NpyVwImkOj8aUk6Unxsh6HSd65v4tZbgoJcVsyggSorMJyH659nbRgpXmU2PUd6iXieqRuHJT8wCGdIMm6XdnnbJidycrF",
"AL18jRC7zMw5Xv43901876dEOZGUVNqvzsDSjf0S2wY0133b35jbbwPZvwUqjlWTNzM7PMZRiYSk1Vv50Ogbk6bQC6hWrdPfNCmDomvHkn1mix",
"3uLky94sCXjRluK4QcrBNkNjEiyABFtFafZJp4b11uTnYDrPQSqDddXRwvr8aVNlaM4ARfBSKufJ8HyYzYCNczEI56Qg1DBcqFMhVoaGTpp17X",
"2ldCazbeUaY3B5Id9fGPPkD0KTfrZWS2i5FsFRHz1GCDLlQUAwKpRoqChG3hDVjV1ZoGQ6fRNSvydltOSdeKBFmTlpbYlvUmuj2kqhcdaHMo3f",
"ANzCDN6LNykDW84BLhly50LWPFl83DJEqjg46mPTVaxRiCt4UOCZPoVF3gN6UxLlQ1pXofRjqobJ1FNVupUjNQYQ6MX1kInaKM892ZssoEbqjY",
"KzDCXnZ2va3e7LrqgUZkwbIbi1ucapKVYoxWMwZhH2wPOYf4Seppp8BI96UjvFeu3LrPiq70tEPhD4mvjLVJUxr3Dmm92BE6m5WFw4FZIuhlzD",
"OEbUmNo4tzACFHAlYGb17y9K2zFJK1oyFAt2nS7RrHu7o4snLEoTcyDf7jYRkmqZXU2kM9bdQGlfLNCws1qEz3UGmSyHfZGcTIwGSIUIpfYa3B",
"DxHeToVQEYeqqAM1WGUYHW4OJN6PNq1rXJFR7BHMzWd0wZ2tGXrnTwcDjjt7KuyHedymPg8pclpJlsc1pDpj9CXtVqAFV8n9mWvbcEBpZ08ktk",
"ZoPnaqlyC2Cy2E20dUIVyId9LAN3NAVNZLa9bwHNzkmBZpCdjl8S3m1OWOSKpNxozIyKfgyOBUpAj1NCmWvqjwegl61LUy9thIewYMkAGKa0LY",
"CcbaFD7nDfcPd0xFu8Pw5DUiRkiMqd02pcd5PksszFhNFPtaYiG3WAlNVEAlRBohNBmCWP5wumjacMka50d1BzPwdqS51hmOSJrPzwl3TFe5ry",
"5joXMrlyXsEC0oVHlyjzYThp4UWJ0k76Dw4qYpYVSCxS1tAm1TWZNdpR8lA9GIfkfjKdJJ8BlFun84KaYGaLTAD2WebCWqWcKHptqx5MdA9mFT",
"Ki7j43Q4ooW4fiLGK2uKbr0ueNo0WRFGaN0eRRigfelux6ai8F2j73OmRdmN42ufPutHmLXB0i6xohPxWSR4VFqMTNAYP4dFzGmVrjwsCCZ0TP",
"tpJu4mYtgqjQZQ7h23ieTc54OIJGL6HevqJANI348nU8d1pf5ItYVz3JhNq3T8ioz1ZmK2qTql2DnrTsanq5WuPdhghaozzXByklBLf16hFtJy",
"PPCZK9s1R96wCNYWRgbNxUsAgXILb5t0V50FfsG7BNEdBCatSlgqgJ1wHJhSOKSJQSp6l5dWTRavulYmGfNWYOtFxKymvq6mjvsEBGBvyL026Z",
"qxOQGfihHtyEXRasRB3xHodFwVMNRbMiJB9pRrHyVfdT7nlYYowGNJlkE87wkTO3vXsmpaUkp8exvzvuY1aMKw6pFdWZ7K2DIvZ7FUs52GCxg8",
"vUJdsLgbhckW5lLlySEt1z6jXdE0cSOHNyVfjbqAoLxt6jOFbt9c3fw0ta0F2PnQoi5HuwiShQlo9a3kDcwHs2HVdIBgyY6WgbDKHWDZMYnV9q",
"UnT2d1N250lNj4w1RKQUiYlA78PaeIR86KbkLYmRYHFiLbjDVaxd8TOf2Eqgnhpt2ANOy9GxRlQDwagslOGuHuKK9a1wsqZv1MjAWZ8NkZrR9H",
"bBa30xEJExW7zpeXK1GZ2ID6xLBwF3ERFPUFmzp17m8GLnDwokvq38xAT87zbLqQBlwXUWY1i7I3umATG5jJdQk7YsHae80PtxMntLpMT7Qotq",
"SDUGOvP0mFBLtXvSIGaKv0EZYdCTk3xdGrTvWJvjp74S4ALNhWyMWcLVpoOKrlX7NRDKB830g8TkIE80AGMxSysiWh2oD0wqS9buifuynnT621",
"9ek36gK1PsRYt87xDxukV4mGwiWoIiFRw0UCgFE57v4BEb9hJECEIYlfgiDYAiP7iKJzpoFxTJ9xViPFWrjEqFUHXxGxQvF9gpIGNndH7nf2F4",
"Yz3PwmQeLESssSxvcS2s9kgzEFHE0QTZpWOWiEa4j3wMV3h8WjA6EQGiwoWwePvEMkA5ZL9iOF4KJmSGFtMjktCQRzn6pTKbdlgc7pvV5AGOWy",
"1HZVyENCsbcmiVoVERZT0rrXfBkzgwGieFeMj1oLdB7wwwrbnq5nSxl78GGocmHq1WdlYC7bdfHKL9V8A1wsyRAGyg5KDNbFJo1I08TdoBYaLT",
"OIJE3h1FFyXv5MnvoiQVSixMSS5FYUDMCmrGEtlk1jP75dCtwtpoLXaEPgjOaXANk2tYvPjx88EelhISK8gw5raVHuJSrkGLmaKSZ3p8c4mym5",
"N84mZd53XtTkFDOGPCz37xhTfahB3phRyldyzjBxMuRr8G8YiI1qfijvtA7w0oozJB7jVIQHdI9mpikI0l8fDsL72SE3g2C0EKkztbgHTq3jIn",
"awWxIB2NT7Vck38gTEu9sh5iGHPiY018xXGfzI3sQYFa2NqVsV5UcadTS3bQ3dZBaFQKoTceSRoUFPQ7KV2X6gQZj2PnfPYqvPaTJn8BexwTmm",
"sYCfUw6dWoyIp3FqKS0qlqWA0ZpGuMyXKacFHjTDHrm6v2xfUxFfXCQYBfF62d3Nogs5zlIgN4ni6Uy1sdgpP6oqm3xohAbFREKr0tINx56E0E",
"aIY9XPJ14MImaUL2PaR2CH61nTLJO8hYQf8N4RO9DxvNrhPhrGk4oq5LkQv8YM6O2eC75qhJYNwq4mHw32ArsFdMwJUvw1kygWGmnX5lLCLPYt",
"3d46eNJ5eS4f1U7XvEwM3pBw6f6hkPHo3LuhzenO6s47nb4SQAFU0hr6xxoRm5gpRKHrZ5g5xkcUwhNnSshSKJZhgn9Dtp3laLM9Q2fonrjUJ6",
"5e1ZTyh408dZQnMqtsbToo20szjxKUsP9uP22772gk16HOxbgJ4E77FzGZ7qTzg23656ec8ux9BfY9qeSvSZDyyjyGKrg1uk8AqmMyRjItyGCZ",
"lTEux3ECKtrTDFUs973xRQlO8NgeYrojl3OS6suRWVKzBE1LM5iEVEs4rJipaHIvKwoQZSIWOsvq7xbTDuxy80DzJVZUDHqoeOeeHXawpGWxe8",
"g8TxqvW732RCBgIDRGeQiCdwLUNzhvaxD444z1bC43fFjYjaFx0YaeuV8iupNFXrJ2vj4GW8KbN3a6ePEfNOtiKCAf2nV0OE3jY70UfL62Ph93",
"uymiLAA91UfNgc0qkDBe7xPUPALjgnwKVT2HtDQuy6iOijfCXRQ5oGZehKxx83h4WkLqYCVxIem1yCEvtvARbA5slC0tGiyDCk4BW08FevHM7l",
"x9wursUtNAaop0SdSifahlHTewFLUXmr7SVzkQ28qcwQdp35IjgZFXTUuyFow1QETMeeCgm2tTSGjWM1g21V0UPutuS0wIFquTE7919DU2jdZ5",
"suKdEITgYGKHKAAYJpM21Kf9BAtBOhZgLKuqsnGr3q9N1KMLayNbj3lVDOws6wISgciJAZbDqkrs4edeN1q74L2IAyaG4Syl5R4FRfjhALKFZX",
"vl4L8u3GP85KGYN86WWta1KsDgOd3NPz9TkhnoYdx3Xd2Ll9HiCSknkXD8aHW0h5UCmi1lwyotMrf8AXrcPLAaJdjTVfUdlOPI7R3Dqs7cTmlu",
"YnFTIvsQ0DalYojSBq0BD2nFgn8XrApqY5jGBMwCpHXn6ggHHhjkjG0A38yvJXVH3eoE0UgqCdOIu4qblJwFqxftGNZpLU7P9vtaqKA2XpLstb",
"sBwvO0zxh3hGNdqMg01xCLUMg8uxC4y4F5Au691ndj40xvNNvPl7AfURnoo0sX583FD9OFw2ZA2w5PkAFFIgVD7i1wjutoCx3gGSVcUUNXrSNL",
"1TB96SZMDl5XguCiUDR5Bb0gUzUaZji0cUaiMa4pvanLEZ4zCVEe7Fu2fpceIvfUppdcAiC5tZR7YVHARmOY1i0hHdvqILl8bykLRWQkVHrTD9",
"aGVBrVnJlKnvaHpTWmcqqmHg1mdhN0AXHvy8qVSMGghRXGKU3Wktj2JkoXCcYcaFHIO8EGUkWcbUTVOWS9pcb9xA69M5lWK3Fybjf6EciQ6bMV",
"pEg8gLqkrlgV5CG9EGRmaVgULjTSWC2mhivx4VSvh8rnK7wpNoMYk2S5mMXio0EFj9dn55TmekJYrfoeEacYd53zR1Rg1wVkG9ILeB7tWQrn6Q",
"iVX0zXc7yh3KvvNMPUXHjSwBafY3Nh95c76L4iTCAXn6sbSh5QZpIw0TLZWzg6FtdMfh49UF6hLzsERyuQXdnY79X3Ie9oHnaXEf6zUdQGMjkD",
"FntRDfx0TGi8yAAHWE4Dy1CFMAU2tGA9430HiyIce1lNCWvzAzc9AOPnoKpSr01v32dmBWzQXUEzQ98rIlBjaqGzb6rC6t7awlx7h6Xf1BPSLX",
"ck1n6Me3xZLL2Up5MYDa0ay7fEaPAucMOdaVZoZxoKiqFHvrG9CHjaOzOYootAbiNleNKdk8XDzDk441eHIxRx6Fwv4Z5fiSBwGlJ0uHD3kY8o",
"wdGvSVxDRaohDr2RpKo8b6wZBvwEkGIQTomMjTpb3OsGguyGfWOq2lqDQXibD02xpojIhITlxm2NRAt6wiwyDXcuUvFxvI5V6oDo6xKDUMrLmU",
"1soYOKlbDUtmISnrn9izlM1fnw78dBYe3mdR7z3Ltx8cpwENFWn0Jpg7Wng9Zeo2BBUJbYvFvERVavIPs6Qbv6iruyBtNZwpBq8MoErUijPsOx",
"OKypJ6Pp5ejQklvDmxj0STCoqVZggLP5vouevjDAyXqTiVxFsQFlJiJ9eIqutgAZE4d9oRKXPaQ76nNzdtUWMD60mxvPN5Osa2BzUmwJxnRDKE",
"0BzlNDbTSHqH2bc20eNXer5bl2CLyoPz0pUO26HVN8CQjOTj2Ghh8mstp4eXt4wutqivx0qk83bsR4LUL3bTqEmPJBMdFjH8K0Eh15C98NB0Sn",
"BQxCWYm2XsrC1pGB1PerYEOeRL0X1n2CezfbyBdw4F864PH5EWxCBlRs6Sq7gsKu20FABT6GyfMD5uJJqgm1BeuI6VQnoBRqCx1dr8T0nGDsan",
"1RxR2HK3vHQOOnOFqF7XuknIzswuyv8zmGrpoctTTkHIHwo7bv5GQsoqVVVtr43OKve9HH2B1KjIhHQtdV93oyujtpMVtQJelYn2FqDGaXpsFf",
"41Kh52liId51w1iAtkrBYUkZRWVM3qU7sEpyGLQpYWqvXI5r3x22rm1iiX5mo0tQFTomEfLCcb7aUdBYKD0b02uj0AFoB9eg2DCHTnk5zrfuEQ",
"iZ8CjVT6FVUtXS9Xc5Hq9e9hOi2LicpBcxdwt7C92xC0pMXCSF31TcjHumtNyToLqChUJT4MqHNQtKtmpwojIH0d4u0DnooO1FJLzNxZukQY5j",
"mP0qHsb12K13p6C5ISg2tAwAST7t6gut5vUMX5OZPP3fVFkEyAG1bdC36Kxc11G6wATuFHtvxxKtc47KFOMQ1pU7arkbt0i0BbugTYLqvwUIB1",
"CBcMwWNx2Y4vFk0DiNx1w6fSKZLAi9lVLxHhtvPwuU19e2NwQkymrNfcN0N6a81VGJdae3GIXISbLFIB0gYs4dESerYoAZkgIyqXB7FyPyKAes",
"NqzHzbZPXN6twCSTvMjYt4o95KLcoxmbXWTx7Sm5Gsyd5r6BdpzHuYQAICM7a9i75bEd40jKtRXzj4awuKeYI5yrIlySuQZA2EN7F7R9YPIhTS",
"ah9I1bpDHKyaN6B9G0dD2VvAncfbssTDJ2lLeLpVvY6i4HrKIFoKBUlY7A9z22dM5yyjkXfPVm8Z3AJMf8xQ2SPatZJw1Wj7vRrPOHFK3OJ7ot",
"lxFSvfZW6p01hvATKyDCWH3B67NKrUxNscGXsFTy4UzmqafbJTNFARhHY4sqZ0drcTpEzidDdM0DXfOG9BmKtDrrIURIU497YzMxRZb4MbIKrw",
"ft3C2sAMNaGlWhBD5XNXBfgVP038OdK3HNGJghv4rcpnt01zXOwz3MuTNx1BLMFszmcPDIT4UisojtXhiuQmglf4ShGE3l7CIjsl2mqWFTkYmi",
"CGivjFoYDRlBmdgB6lBtU30KtUslpPh1wzxPfVOSM9u8nKKt5mWZpXJTSceh1vjx5QmkLadykHHIssbyO8xe6h7YulgvRz3WqqhcBuLVcsDEVP",
"pm0v8p2MmUAIC9fVyCCGcR2J8fvWHJL65LCdbE0xzBgcKw8j8KZlC14KhAHYjs5peIDqmEYWff90LhjT2jfElkpCV6BfzHEOpieMWdJcsScdaw",
"qcgmWXlonOxrl4SOxm8xAn8NLYI0zz7ZLnmHlH6JwEaRI3FfqOM0bUOXTxXs65rRtNzOvGy1kIT2Myicn4dyZ2wSztlFyNx1A6Q6No7870aTzs",
"QO2stD1jd6csvW7ueTeTwP7FELrxNzgDni6RV8a8enBKjJfxCtq9iyPXkgu7QKLd3R5ZZf8eDKYWtdu6HVfZu4XOlrVccGpgyvfxLoLo8KkCYP",
"XtX7DtuH0HQlVecEu1o0YzbCypNwfiVcMTjpnO7owYKrcW5HYuHX3SzBim8xE4KqY4QlSYJoXtQ9qWRoqymtrV5JidhWh1ng6eBYdlnaOdkf9b",
"pOgJSpRnpLedr6QVV4Uc8M7Loez7bngAcwk4WcslXHzoNpkJufVC23oqhYytmO4ykoDgA5CyMbWABhj5wfIyj7YA5w4rl80FxDW7JzGwLC7mTq",
"ND0Y2aYgc2wlQ3yi5aW4ZSs80uw4jpN63O56Y3mb5TxWX5e3fb8f4An44T8ojWvnLAtJDQVJJsFHyUKO5S39sqexjnVDkq051tPFkKo4d3LLXv",
"hxWH8kIzKB0jomex4OgkuNwSBnsac2rtzoaIIShtuiNTE1qJPH4kuAc5YFfaHHDh5OZOHhibz54e7uXWb2hGCuLB91LRJp8Pd8DVpV6Y1bd8Gb",
"Ft2VRbavlJqg4iqtJzE7jEnW5LpmIRpolsjdDtIYd8fhrFKaepiy3Fv8rUvaMVy7nSl0l4ZzdeQEUBO916H5Mcde7JoTFW12Om3aq2JEgAiac7",
"JvcqyGGDRm1i3zphjhRETotJi64Sxj2hPfHnVn1NK36NCv4VNVAGk3qD9vwHOzYDOG0K41yO4EBH9GDWCdDWg4Aqz67nF60uM1fR3NF8rhPAYt",
"9Sk8iONT26wmJLnKFkyqDDhimRlcWsT6leeE31x574sQPQBvaaWNOd6a5sn2Ug8fvnUyprEwv6nlWZR7aNVY1187uv9oMhEhEyQ30uAwBYSyYJ",
"0xl6cmbMoSEE2OpXiL26VEFm9PCGPcJQJ5WWs7IQ0mv3aU1tG3ABHfYR5BxUNhKxnHtPPbGPybTI6UcMYNoG2nx8Y52MnNjKuMAjYg9wr2fxXs",
"8pncTqgpwdxeM9Q1zIbGZB3dKptGJeKRD84xykW5xukkDamdTyTS9W5UmzB5OmWru1Z3lW8Trte5EAix8bpi8vcu4NzT9wlExkHTgQMHj0MXB4",
"YphSzYYb5lALzqwfXMv92ZEUO8LPvB9u0rmApkLvGlggLNwJA1SC1wxPFjFaUPEVg1vGmgb2CsjogP7QQZtRw0Hbjnmec1at2F9oWlrzOKX4A4",
"yEGbuGhngySjN0L7efnkZro6tDMVPU1oyIz3pQqGoi0ciMjx1GS08h6CUTyKNA8liIoIyPoX7oaqbtYcaQdj8jV2cuM04VlnDK5czt9HSk83O6",
"gxJ84TMIQxjvA0fG4QkMDq9gToPEP075yReCL0lCxF77GnNKe7wRyG7r4X6TYeZw5d8RdutL9BSPYGAcO63mMbOR8UK78KDeXM6bgzXqaPg9wQ",
"pmHdFhKBmpe6y3OiFdTCiiZlLbQcPnUfJBsoSd0fCembhatXomzGEz1qLSDBfxQY9in2woh8DDjVOMSc9sTO1UfNMTo2qe1AxoC3MTcqxwlljd",
"91hERc7xmVu9ADbh4LACL7SXvpOMTPD3QVII8PfuKKDkoPBsAb4miXjOn8AgXdkO92whRMLCxpXVeyoOKtb3ruRODr5AFpoOsV6kHRWegTausy",
"e1SfTMPf2vYtZG8CPKF3ZrASA4LcIZPX1IcVv2axy91xQa9GUPJUhkMRox37xT4zBhu7jFFRPHpFRzlMp5GGptxO1AVzt085hDdBiSt7zSNrs8",
"fC7QsYHQK5kE7YxqZ01SPivIhhiAq1RFDZw5YeWIkhnrfUReVS7KbDtsUL2kNU0qTxwRLtA6KXxZSpeNilyuY1XTNZeAUf1OMyFy1gELdcK6CY",
"tgw0q3hbq6kEtb0YHqFjG8CG2HSx7aFAqbARfS3GYnlrymqfN5ztecahU3O1dtBEFcwV4zC2XXuvjVL61kAfxKwrNls1O4GugdplM1oJZSfiO0",
"k930lDiLl1JxWLpUQzjMB3x405N5nrdHAhHWU0Hg2rOYcdS3NcQofosftglQHyyiQgeLgW1inPhA39ERmugBSIRmZccGLKZB1dmiaoAydS8h2M",
"T5jWoWBVEqhwIg7GPd9806046wfX026T7qPwmrr0RJxAZFhOSqWSxXWDubBudHol7eStGjuy2181GqQzQNrnLo1fACKOk8arn2V3lqBosKp9ag",
"KrEpeu7uB8fGbRperilZO0rVhLopz9nkB1JPwRk7ZzObrdpSwLRkLig34EsEOPYqRIfnzAuz9jKBxat3WloHEFKIjdn83lyU3OiDoMcy6XaD7E",
"zVuaB7nxZSFY4jucNX3qoIzoLve2IHpiCUse1PL1Ir0MKuYyr2ZPKyev3syMaX4MSw0UmMV4eWRZqPySSxID5W89pGVzEZmwwnrSanXojOoJEW",
"TrzBrFWhaiUCn2A66IOufc4tzea9a9v4B5F2LCkVUfyih8onRdR6pWAZaK8lTEquK6xvISrC70Uo8iM0vD6VzHUKr26lHwQrCoWkgoXooRMxay",
"1fXajFfoEPwG2Jv3Oq9o59c6fQamHdHItETMk8aYYGE0qa4fBdDGnQNCHXZobG7El0qG9BE8hj8IudX5qBLNsyq9wpyI6FmsGN8QoMYG67pAkm",
"CXjENwG2BDU0EmmORCKb3e1Kbr6Sc52P2ltPS9RtMLuq8Rf0t0bxechqEoiRtlGwH9lzjd35Zxw8oL8SLjp0wHqb5J3z4J5LTrlcFoiEWPNlBV",
"N918EyaHZNfVZ99Vo62SU94za2R2CzTqJVyntI5swkovuxrTEtLzDP8NS0QvAJVjFuH9cMCJ60eBxGuc9fLN5UAXUrtuboNQSu05gCOnC3YaJt",
"XBSgip6faPWBwmVDTOCn7K2xo0VjKQfIs7YKx50HUWjrjf4c4HzbsCJQCEanvp5Xw4H39HL4E4vXjzanhJzJlizXXKks9qpFu7JEPuIuydrSNB",
"b6LLimNDYdUnmnLuMbIBKjAcLJeQQUY20KOi7BW6PRubefG0qpCaJdnuXBlNwjQx4EQcgNi5ENhT2XUtmwE5K1AHDVv9flHk0xwglPlZCCTFAN",
"XWQcPiVAGK61xoMZjrc3fAlDs15vUzqSwg4mz0WfL3gir3iLuuOJ4anxbt262tZzK4Vj4SyQVP9mSr8nVW6Z6uxiYzo02nAMrw6woEnjuwGmXO",
"QAQWsDymaHcGBOHqH4ojTH7wC1tCqvVh5MdyqMUBt7h4VYuD3TWWB4sd5WQwrLOxy16YO1zh8Rm4PRHSKEPmIhAOeqkGc8dKakIYligt9DxZuf",
"nVlidzlgp9UQMfwVDv2AnklRphuFPWfcRAu4aQlz0fpNvWI8rLJP54Gvlbba7qnZ1S4bJpKJFaxa6gjy12o674CsgNDnd1nfTrqCQbmwmTHta1",
"uown1KPMzPZr24PBYQfTYk0rMbjfejPIHm5I7VvHKu9MzYoxPDrNXrfKDyZRSPzzbFhjAM0lha8R9wpYaRL8j0SWzSOrHo1T3jcE6dZon7fwEF",
"izD5eDdMnxNyq4reEoisZFo36sV7Ks532I8gll3JTQhjVJyz7Q17vqaCS5JDyOGAxORTaUC3LTnGDVgKLhShH3TA9DeHsUiZJaTU4vYQplw2hM",
"CMVF5LznrvbW0uSoK8wWEgaky7NZFq5id1XiNxGe2Rb3m3r6cY3QfdaNkYN0oTiCUfVINBWQt8TPbkWojZeydpmyn9yM3QoX6kFTVCJpKCeWXa",
"cEUPsQV8eq3knQvSI90YL9OhsLKaPlX10RQtIMBWdFgAvMteWtdID106MKhC6eD66uzOhbLuQ24lOyAL2NtFPtLCd2ejhRqnmZcDaY700cmPKX",
"jwzlvApoOyslkf2BsJj79Qax64RVpLXJiw4N7tbV2EhmTjYm2huc7EJeJB98m6SFDWsKqEGsjXPcgNzi43vcIeqrPAAcGsSjpk4PZKhiH6uYU3",
"syFBPjNoCZwf1aSA328mlmssAltIxSnZq3BgmpEZobfqm71p9aMvweX6zrO7jc7KfJ1B8FBxRQXdYZD79pDFEAMd2BlmNt72c8ElOfSF6QT4Pw",
"09OhQx7j4M4qBOcRklwlwuDymVZiFHUGRIXHg40kQ5LrTXjejPzQkdoG9oYP6SvYBsFSwGdnMYPGW8UfXu5hHuYQSWFZPaXrDDjakxx7vnNrvI",
"WxyY6IVCmXFb9wSnjOx4pAyMP0FPjyAg68ecQaPd7uog1hDl5bpvLYiBYYqiw0yC8NPZXFc49BlbSZxYbXuWVNyTLYchZLU8yK8wpkByWWKPVh",
"RvSNH2tsVDSDTrZyMcFa43sWluzb7EUZaMNSPhkKUdoNEnmrA2CE55BrzbCHPwGZjuR8LcTFqht4FPwfR8UXewoNH0uxxbxRFpZqBT62bz7QpD",
"GKmxnXyK2hFU8SAjjzWIJ46OqbjN8OdPzAmWxUGAcmvkf5EyFAhoFod6AwTJl6yUHVRfPyP1Vkmaq0J5B1tgpGmZcgJymhs4ckj2S84NtrXTrH",
"39avrM0zV4IO8c18s0AexlREC7R0vMDyWO3oA4Xv9GkhTlqll1ATnrxZzo04bDC7rGv2KsxU8Rc2dCnzEXs1p01Yp12AFEH7ld95GH0OzcRMPe"
);

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
else
{       echo "connected fine.<br>";
}



function generateRandomString($length = 110) {
  $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  $randomString = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
  }
  return $randomString;
}

function create100() {
  global $con;
  $query = "INSERT INTO authid (authid) VALUES ('";

  echo "begin generate random inserts<br>";
  for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++)
  {  /*echo $query.$RandomString."')";*/
     $RandomString=generateRandomString();
     /*echo $RandomString."<br>";*/
     /*echo $query.$RandomString."')"."<br>";*/
     $result=$con->query($query.$RandomString."')");

     if (!$result) {
       printf("%s\n", $mysqli->error);
     }
  }
  echo "end generate random inserts<br>";
}

$command=$_GET['action'];

if ($command=="create100")
{  create100();
}

if ($command=="findme")
{   echo "begin find me<br>";
    $iCounts=0;
    $beginTime = microtime(true);
    for ($i=1;$i<=1;$i++)
    {   for ($j=0;$j<211;$j++)
        {  
            $query = "select authid from authid where authid='".$authids[$j]."'";
            /*echo $query."<br>";*/
            $result=$con->query($query);

            /*printf("Select returned %d rows.<br>", mysqli_num_rows($result));*/

            if (!$result) {
            printf("%s\n", $mysqli->error);
            }

            /*echo $result."<br>";*/
            $iCounts++;
        }
    }
    $endTime = microtime(true);
    printf("findme found %d ids in %01.3f seconds, %01.3f rows/sec<br>",$iCounts,$endTime-$beginTime,$iCounts/($endTime-$beginTime));
}

?>
```

Comment: remember, php is not exactly a speed demon. if you can take care of key population ahead of time and secure it then it should be considered at least, though it has its own complexities, like what happens when you run out. do you have a cron job that kicks off now and then and repopulates, do you dog, delete, or archive them. naturally this key size is pretty large (110 chars) but it illustrates the time required to generate them and do inserts, which can be done ahead of time. good luck

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to implement a password-reset function, or something similar with a one-time token?

If this token will grant access to a user account, then you should consider this: The token should not be stored plaintext in the database, instead it should be handled like a password. That means that only a hash of the token ist stored in the database, an this implicates, that you cannot search for this token in the database table anyway.

One way to solve this problem is, that the row-id will become part of the token. The tokens are not required to be unique then (no check), the row-id makes them unique. I wrote a PHP class, that helps [generating one-time tokens](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#passwordreset) for password-resets, and allows to validate them. It can be used likewise for other purposes.

Comment: Well the key is just to authenticate ajax requests so that other sites don't use my ajax pages. But, I will have a look at tokens, I've heard of them before but never actually tried them out. Thanks!